# Having difficulty placing Bounty on a question

Tags: support, bug

I attempted just now (several times, with and without various "refreshes") to place a Bounty on [this question from History.StackExchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43189/can-anyone-find-a-picture-of-nsdap-kpd-workers-eating-lunch-together-in-1932-d). The *Bounty* dialog appears, but when I select an amount of **50 rep**, neither the ***Next*** or ***cancel*** controls has any affect. The ***X-close*** control does work, and the ***Next*** button does go a darker shade of orange when I click it.

Same behaviour occurs if I select a bounty of **100-rep**, so it's not just that I must specify a larger amount.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I have not placed a bounty on a question before.

Comment: Are you by any chance using IE11?

Comment: @Ano: Yes - Is the answer really that simple?

Comment: Since IE11 is used by very few people (3% last time I checked), most likely this bug won't be fixed any time soon. Several months are probably the best case, might be much longer. (or never, since IE11 will become obsolute at some point.) Bottom line: to use SE properly download and use Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I am in the process of moving to Chrome. StackExchange bookmarks now moved.